# Open terminal with telnet from command

Tags: macos, bash

I'd like to open a telnet sessions from a sublime text build process. I've tried using

```
open /bin/bash --args telnet 127.0.0.1
```

but that fails .. is there anything similar I can do?

**Edit**

I'm trying to open telnet as at work we use telnet to access our debugger.
When I build in sublime it's a little annoying to have to manually click over to `telnet`
 - so ideally I'd just like sublime to set focus to an already running telnet session however it seemed easier to just grab the pid of telnet - kill it and open a new one.

I should also point out I'm using OS X

Comment: An interactive telnet session?

Comment: Excuse me im asking here but can anybody explain for me what is the relationship between a text editor `sublime text` and telnet command?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, after you have the telnet session open? Might there be a way to accomplish that more directly (almost certainly yes)

Comment: @Crl What was the error and are you on Sublime Text 2 or 3? TechLife: I think he was just doing the scripting through Sublime Text's automation tool

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
spawn telnet localhost
set timeout 10
expect "debian login"
send "test\r"
expect "Password:"
send "password\r" 
expect "*$*"
send "ls\r"
expect "*$*"
send "logout\r"
```